# "Required to call maketrans function"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Why does this not work?

```
from string import maketrans

intab = "aeiou"
outtab = "12345"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

str= "this is string example...wow!!!";
print str.translate(trantab);
```

it says on the that I need to make a maketrans function, what does that exactly mean?
Also it says that print str.translate is an invalid syntax, how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't name a variable `str`; you are masking the built-in type. You also can drop the `;` semicolons in Python; they are rarely needed.

Answer (score 3):

Because in Python 3 [`str.maketrans()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) takes a *dictionary* instead; it appears you are looking at the documentation for Python 2.

The dictionary should map codepoints (integers) to their replacement value (integer or unicode value), or `None` to delete codepoints.

```
intab = "aeiou"
outtab = "12345"
trantab = str.maketrans(intab, outtab)

mystr.translate(trantab)
```

There is no need to import `string.maketrans` for this job; the [`str.maketrans()` static function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) is available to do the job.

Demo:

```
>>> intab = "aeiou"
>>> outtab = "12345"
>>> trantab = str.maketrans(intab, outtab)
>>> mystr = "this is string example...wow!!!"
>>> mystr.translate(trantab)
'th3s 3s str3ng 2x1mpl2...w4w!!!'
```

From the [`str.translate()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

> Return a copy of the s where all characters have been mapped through the *map* which must be a dictionary of Unicode ordinals (integers) to Unicode ordinals, strings or `None`. Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to `None` are deleted.

Incidentally, Python 2 `unicode.translate()` also works this way, while in Python 3, [`bytes.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.translate) also uses the old API.